# Saving one record using Google Cloud Functions and then overwriting it

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I'm working with gmail API and need to save the historyID to determine the changes that happened in the email from the pubsub events.

However, I don't need to store all the historyIDs and just need to pull the old historyID, use it in my function, and overwrite it with the new one.

Wondering what kind of architecture would be best for this. I can't use the temp storage of google cloud functions because it would not be persistent.

Using google sheets requires extra authorization within the cloud function. Do I really need to make a new cloud bucket for one text file?

Comment: Why don't you use Firebase Realtime database (https://firebase.google.com/docs/database) or Firestore (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore)?

Comment: Will check it out, trying to see if there was some other way than setting up a db.

Comment: I have the exact same issue, did you ever come up with a slick solution?

Comment: I did not. You can either save it to a db or cloud storage.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like [Cloud Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/) would be your best alternative to Cloud Storage if your use case is to persist, retrieve and update the historyID as log data at low-cost. Using Google Cloud Functions and Cloud Datastore would be like a server-less log system.

Datastore is a NoSQL document database built for automatic scaling, high performance, and ease of application development. It can handle large amount of non-relational data with relatively low price. It also has a user-friendly [Web Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/datastore/entities/).

I found a very useful web tutorial which you can use to help you architect a Cloud Functions with Cloud Datastore solution like so:

- Create Cloud Datastore
- Obtain Datastore Credential
- Update your Code
- Deploy your Cloud Function
- Send a Request to Cloud Function
- Check the Log on Datastore

Take a look at the full tutorial [here](https://medium.com/@chriswrite/cloud-function-and-datastore-tutorial-intro-to-build-a-server-less-service-92bc106ef8e5). Hope this helps you.